# Limit of multiplication of exponentiated linear factors exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

Say I have some collection of numbers $a_i$ and $b_i$ with $\sum_{i=1}^n b_i = 0$. Then, what is the limit of the expression:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}  \prod_{i=1}^n(x + a_i)^{b_i} $$

Intuitively, since the sum of the exponents is $0$, it seems to me that the function tends to move like a constant function. For particular choices I tested, it in fact converges but even when it did, I did not see a nice formula in terms of $a_i$ and $b_i$.

Does it always converge? And if yes, is there a general formula for the limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n(x + a_i)^{b_i} = \prod_{i=1}^n \bigg( \bigg( 1 + \frac{a_i}x \bigg)^{b_i} x^{b_i} \bigg) = \bigg( \prod_{i=1}^n \bigg( 1 + \frac{a_i}x \bigg)^{b_i} \bigg) x^{\sum_{i=1}^n b_i}.
$$